# HTML5 Drag and Drop for a "fill in the blanks"

Tags: html, forms, canvas, drag-and-drop

I want to create a "drag and drop" for a "fill the gaps" style question, then submit this data through a HTML form.

**Example:**
[image]

I have looked at a few ways of doing this, such as dragging and dropping images - not what I want, or [dragging and dropping elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)* on a page but I can't figure out how I can make this in to a form input.

- Apologies for the W3 Schools link, I know they are not liked around here

Comment: Is html canvas needed for this?  Maybe something like this (some assembly required!): Create a div with green background containing a paragraph element with your "drag" word.  Ditto with "drop".  Use jqueryUI to make the divs draggable.  Create div drop targets containing "______".  Then use javascript to respond when the "drag" is dropped in the drop target.  Populate a standard HTML form with the results and submit with AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the example you linked gives you:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .draggable {background-color:#00ff00;margin:5px;padding:3px;}
      #div1,#div2 {display:inline-block;min-width:25px;min-height:10px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-bottom-width:2px;}
    </style>
    <script>
      function allowDrop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
      }
      function drag(ev){
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
      }
      function drop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.parentNode.replaceChild(document.getElementById(data), ev.target);
        document.getElementById(data).className = "";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="draggable" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">drag</span>
    <span class="draggable" id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">drop</span>
    <br />
    This is a sample 
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    and 
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    sentence.
  </body>
</html>
```

[Here's a fiddle of it to play with.](http://jsfiddle.net/3Nxxa/)